# Back navigation between fragments Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a main activity with multiple fragments showing one after the other.
I need to implement the back button navigation, so that when it is pressed it brings the last fragment up and remove the current one. Basically just like it is done with Activities.

From what I understand the best way is to handle the onbackPressed in the main activity. But how do I get the last Fragment and replace the current one. Here is how I show fragments:

```
 public void showFragment(String name) {
        Fragment fragment;
        switch(name){
            case "new_trip_1":
                fragment = new newTrip_step1_Fragment();
                break;
            case "new_trip_2":
                fragment = new newTrip_step2_Fragment();
                break;
            default:
                fragment = new dashboard_Fragment();
                break;
        }

        final FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).addToBackStack(name).commit();
    }
```

Comment: just a little of googling https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html

Comment: You could consider a completely different approach by [using a custom backstack library, and manage the fragments with `add`/`remove`/`attach`/`detach` methods of FragmentTransaction](https://hackernoon.com/simplified-fragment-navigation-using-a-custom-backstack-552e06961257#.yyo2ajuzj).